# Remove number from url keys of category and product after adding url prefix Magento 1.9

Tags: php, mysql, magento, url, magento-1.9

I have tried every possible solution found online to remove keys from Urls but i am failed. The urls were fine before i added prefix to url like

Categories URL:     www.example.com/category-name/someString/sub-category.html

Product URL:        www.example.com/category-name/p/product-name.html

Now its looks like followings.

Categories URL:

www.example.com/category-1.html

www.example.com/category-123.html

Product URL:

www.example.com/category-name/p/product-123.html

www.example.com/category-name/p/product-2345.html

Things i have found and already tried:

truncate the table core_url_rewrite & reindex catalog Url rewirte.

Comment: The integer being added to your urls would indicate you have duplicate urls in your store.  Magento's solution to duplicate url values is to add a unique INT to it so it can root the request correctly.

Comment: @PixieMedia i know that already. I need a solution for it, my categories are not duplicated, this started happen when i had used custom url structure by modifiying the URL.php model file.

Comment: ah ok - didnt know you'd modified a model - suggest you share what you did to it so we can help you further.

Comment: @PixieMedia Details are mentioned above , In addition to that i have change the file **Catalog > Model > Url.php**  to achieve required result and numbers appears with both categories and products.